# Losing mCustomScrollbar effect when performing an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, mcustomscrollbar

I'm using [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) to replace the default scrollbars in a div tag containing a table that I draw using javascript to help me reload it when performing ajax calls, here is my HTML code :

```
<!-- the div that will contain the table-->
<div id="countriesTable" class="customScroll" data-mcs-theme="dark">
</div>
```

Here is the code of the function that loads the data in the table and draws it inside the div

```
function reloadTable(data, id) {
        var str = '<table class="table"><thead>' +                    
                '<tr><th> Column1 </th>' +
                '<th> Column2 </th>' +
                '<th> Column3 </th>' +
                '<th> Column4 </th></tr></thead><tbody>';
        for (var property in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {                    
                str += '<tr>'
                str += '<td>' + data[property][0] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[property][1] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[property][2] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[property][3] + '</td></tr>';
            }
        }
        str += '</tbody></table>';
        $(id).html(str);
    }
```

And of course the call of the function to load data and also the function that applies the custom scroll bar effect :

```
reloadTable(myData, '#countriesTable');
$(".customScroll").mCustomScrollbar();
```

When the page is loaded the div gets the custom scrollbar successfully, but when I perfom an ajax call to reload data into my table, and I draw it another time using reloadTable function I lose the scrollbar effect.
I've tried to recall the mCustomScrollbar inside the ajax success function but in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove current mCustomScrollbar like this:

```
$('.customScroll').mCustomScrollbar("destroy")
$('#countriesTable').html("")
reloadTable(myData, '#countriesTable');
$(".customScroll").mCustomScrollbar();
```